# How can I recover lost files from iPad on Mac?

Tags: ios, ipad, data-recovery

I have stored many videos, contacts, notes, music files and more on my iPad. Unfortunately, I lost my some files on it owing to my wrong operation.

Now I am looking for the ways how to get them back quickly, but everything I have tried has failed.

How can I recover these lost files from iPad on Mac computer?

Comment: Did you have iCloud backup, or have you ever backup your iPad up to iTunes? Also, did you wipe you iPad, or just delete *some* images/contacts/notes/videos/music? Did you happen to get any of the music from iTunes store? Try going to iCloud.com to see if the deleted contacts and notes are there.

Comment: Which app(s) were the files in, and which operation did you do to delete them?

Comment: What have you tried? For an iOS device, you would need to jailbreak the device to gain access to the underlying filesystem. In some cases, the files could still be there, just not in the iOS database, so it won't list it. A jailbroken device can have files that just lost their iOS reference copied off of the device. If the files are gone, then you would need to do a block device copy from the iOS device to your computer, then run file recovery software against the copied raw file. This presumes that you didn't do something like a secure device wipe, which may have just tossed the encryption ke